# Use data from session storage web in Polymer

Tags: javascript, session, polymer

I have a website made with Polymer that when you log in, it returns you in the session storage a key userData with values docID, name, surname and surname2, and then it enters to the platform. Those values are stored in the session storage of the browser.

I want to use those values except the docID and bring it to my code for plot it in the log in view/page, but I don't know how to use the session storage to take those parameters.

I made a fake user but with local storage that works with last time of connection but I don't know how to use it with session and receiving data from a website. This is my script:

```
Polymer({

  date: null,
  timeDate: null,
  keyStorage: 'lastConnection',

ready: function(){
    this.storageDate();
    this.timeDate = this.getLastDateConnection();

    this.storageUser();
    this.fakeUserName = this.getUser();

  },

getLastDateConnection: function(){
    var date = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem(this.keyStorage)));
    return [date.getHours(),('0'+date.getMinutes()).slice(-2)].join(':');
  },

  storageDate: function(){
    localStorage.setItem(this.keyStorage, +new Date);
  },

getUser: function(){
    var name = [localStorage.getItem("firstname") + " " + localStorage.getItem("lastname")];
    return name;
  },

storageUser:function(){
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Vader");
    localStorage.setItem("firstname", "Dark");
  }
});
```

I want to do something similar except I have to storage the user data with session storage and from a website (I don't know the info until someone gets logged), so I suppose that I shouldn't do a setItem and just made a getItem receiving the key "userData" from the website. Any help/idea? Thanks!

PS: Maybe should I store the user info in my local storage after I receive the userData from the session storage if I want to keep the username? What I want to do is something equal to what Google do with our gmail accounts (you logg-in and when you want to enter again, it stores your account).

Comment: It sounds like you want a normal login-system?
If that is the case you need a server-sided script, such as PHP. You would also need a database to store the accounts and their information.

Comment: Not exactly. The login system is already done. The web is made with Polymer. What I want is how to take the key userData with their values that are stored in session storage to my script in the login page for store those values to plot it the next time you want to access to the web. Both the key and the values are provided by the server when you log in and stored in my browser in the session storage. Then I want to use it but I don't know how to do it in javascript.

Comment: localStorage.setItem("name",sessionStorage.getItem("name"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think I got it.

in the ready function is to make the call of the function that storages the session storage with:

```
ready: function(){
    this.setData();
    this.myUser = this.storageUser();
  },

setData: function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("userData",userData);
  },
```

and then storage the session storage in the local making a parse of the object:

```
storageUser: function(){
    var userData = sessionStorage.getItem("userData");
    var myObject = JSON.parse(userData);
    var userName = [myObject.name + " " + myObject.surname];
    return userName;
  },
```

This is working on principle.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but for new people who land on this page, this `session storage` element might be of help. It's behaviour is exactly like `local storage`.

```
    <!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2015 The PlatinumIndustries.pl. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license.
-->

<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<!--
Element access to Web Storage API (window.sessionStorage).

Keeps `value` property in sync with sessionStorage.

Value is saved as json by default.

### Usage:

`Ss-sample` will automatically save changes to its value.

    <dom-module id="ls-sample">
      <iron-sessionstorage name="my-app-storage"
        value="{{cartoon}}"
        on-iron-sessionstorage-load-empty="initializeDefaultCartoon"
      ></iron-sessionstorage>
    </dom-module>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'ls-sample',
        properties: {
          cartoon: {
            type: Object
          }
        },
        // initializes default if nothing has been stored
        initializeDefaultCartoon: function() {
          this.cartoon = {
            name: "Mickey",
            hasEars: true
          }
        },
        // use path set api to propagate changes to sessionstorage
        makeModifications: function() {
          this.set('cartoon.name', "Minions");
          this.set('cartoon.hasEars', false);
        }
      });
    </script>

### Tech notes:

* * `value.*` is observed, and saved on modifications. You must use
    path change notifification methods such as `set()` to modify value
    for changes to be observed.

* * Set `auto-save-disabled` to prevent automatic saving.

* * Value is saved as JSON by default.

* * To delete a key, set value to null

* Element listens to StorageAPI `storage` event, and will reload upon receiving it.

* **Warning**: do not bind value to sub-properties until Polymer
[bug 1550](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1550)
is resolved. session storage will be blown away.
`<iron-sessionstorage value="{{foo.bar}}"` will cause **data loss**.

@demo demo/index.html
@hero hero.svg
-->
<dom-module id="iron-sessionstorage"></dom-module>
<script>

  Polymer({
    is: 'iron-sessionstorage',

    properties: {
      /**
       * SessionStorage item key
       */
      name: {
        type: String,
        value: ''
      },
      /**
       * The data associated with this storage.
       * If set to null item will be deleted.
       * @type {*}
       */
      value: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true
      },

      /**
       * If true: do not convert value to JSON on save/load
       */
      useRaw: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      },

      /**
       * Value will not be saved automatically if true. You'll have to do it manually with `save()`
       */
      autoSaveDisabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      },
      /**
       * Last error encountered while saving/loading items
       */
      errorMessage: {
        type: String,
        notify: true
      },

      /** True if value has been loaded */
      _loaded: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      }
    },

    observers: [
      '_debounceReload(name,useRaw)',
      '_trySaveValue(autoSaveDisabled)',
      '_trySaveValue(value.*)'
    ],

    ready: function() {
      this._boundHandleStorage = this._handleStorage.bind(this);
    },

    attached: function() {
      window.addEventListener('storage', this._boundHandleStorage);
    },

    detached: function() {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', this._boundHandleStorage);
    },

    _handleStorage: function(ev) {
      if (ev.key == this.name) {
        this._load(true);
      }
    },

    _trySaveValue: function() {
      if (this._doNotSave) {
        return;
      }
      if (this._loaded && !this.autoSaveDisabled) {
        this.debounce('save', this.save);
      }
    },

    _debounceReload: function() {
      this.debounce('reload', this.reload);
    },

    /**
     * Loads the value again. Use if you modify
     * sessionStorage using DOM calls, and want to
     * keep this element in sync.
     */
    reload: function() {
      this._loaded = false;
      this._load();
    },

    /**
     * loads value from session storage
     * @param {boolean=} externalChange true if loading changes from a different window
     */
    _load: function(externalChange) {
      var v = window.sessionStorage.getItem(this.name);

      if (v === null) {
        this._loaded = true;
        this._doNotSave = true;  // guard for save watchers
        this.value = null;
        this._doNotSave = false;
        this.fire('iron-sessionstorage-load-empty', { externalChange: externalChange});
      } else {
        if (!this.useRaw) {
          try { // parse value as JSON
            v = JSON.parse(v);
          } catch(x) {
            this.errorMessage = "Could not parse session storage value";
            console.error("could not parse sessionstorage value", v);
            v = null;
          }
        }
        this._loaded = true;
        this._doNotSave = true;
        this.value = v;
        this._doNotSave = false;
        this.fire('iron-sessionstorage-load', { externalChange: externalChange});
      }
    },

    /**
     * Saves the value to localStorage. Call to save if autoSaveDisabled is set.
     * If `value` is null or undefined, deletes localStorage.
     */
    save: function() {
      var v = this.useRaw ? this.value : JSON.stringify(this.value);
      try {
        if (this.value === null || this.value === undefined) {
          window.sessionStorage.removeItem(this.name);
        } else {
          window.sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, /** @type {string} */ (v));
        }
      }
      catch(ex) {
        // Happens in Safari incognito mode,
        this.errorMessage = ex.message;
        console.error("sessionStorage could not be saved. Safari incoginito mode?", ex);
      }
    }

    /**
     * Fired when value loads from localStorage.
     *
     * @event iron-localstorage-load
     * @param {{externalChange:boolean}} detail -
     *     externalChange: true if change occured in different window.
     */

    /**
     * Fired when loaded value does not exist.
     * Event handler can be used to initialize default value.
     *
     * @event iron-localstorage-load-empty
     * @param {{externalChange:boolean}} detail -
     *     externalChange: true if change occured in different window.
     */
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Hey I am trying to use the app-localstorage-document for sessions but can't  figure out how to deal with it. I created a stackquestion maybe you could take a look.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134612/how-to-work-with-app-localstorage-document-in-polymer